# Products from apple developer console not showing inside app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase

I add some in app products in my app and i run it on my simulator. The problem is when the products is not showing for some reason. I tried to re-write the whole screen & set up the payment method but again is not working. I'm beginner on ios development and maybe i'm missing something

**My StoreManager Class:**

```
class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    
    @Published var myProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var request: SKProductsRequest!
    
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    
    func purchaseProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        } else {
            print("User can't make payment.")
        }
    }
    
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
            case .purchased:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                print("payment success")
                transactionState = .purchased
            case .restored:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
            case .failed, .deferred:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .failed
                print("payment failed")
            default:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getProducts(productIDs: [String]) {
        print("Start requesting products ...")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Did receive response")
        
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Request did fail: \(error)")
    }
    
}
```

**My View:**

```
struct PurchasePremiumView: View {
    
    @StateObject var storeManager = StoreManager()
    
    let productIDs = ["Premium"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                List(storeManager.myProducts, id: \.self) { product in
                    
                    Text(product.localizedTitle)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            storeManager.purchaseProduct(product: product)
                        }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            storeManager.getProducts(productIDs: productIDs)
        })
        
    }
}

struct PurchasePremiumView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PurchasePremiumView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your product ID is just "Premium"?

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, is just "Premium"

Comment: Did u submit the screenshot and get it approved? https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devae49fb316

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb57be10e7

Comment: @loremipsum no, what did you mean get approved?

Comment: Look at the first link. Steps 5 and 6